# Naming conflict (_FilterDatabase) when feeding Excel with Data from win32com

Tags: python, excel, win32com

I wanted to create a quick script that pulls data from standardized forms (word docs/docxs) and transports them into an Excel Sheet, with an attached sheet that does some calculating.
Everything works pretty well, with one exception:

I want to be able to filter the results for specific project numbers, user initials or other datapoints, but when I add a filter over the Excel sheet, whenever I run it from Python, I get a "Naming conflict" error messagee and have to choose a new name for "_FilterDatabase" - when I do, the filter is gone.
If I don't, the script crashes.

I open the Sheet like this:

```
import win32com.client as win32
def openExcel():
    xl = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
    wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(path+"\\"+'Analysis.xlsx')
    ws = wb.Sheets(1)
    xl.Visible = True

    return ws
```

Then I pass the datapoints contained in data to Excel

```
def print2Excel(data, ws):
    const = win32.constants
    ws.Range("A2:H2").Insert(const.xlShiftDown, const.xlFormatFromRightOrBelow)
    ws.Cells(2,1).Value = data["datapoint"]
    ...
```

This Problem persists, even when I remove the filter after the fact. As soon as the Excel sheet was filtered once, the error will occur until the end of time. The only way out so far was to *git reset/checkout* the Excel.

Comment: I have this issue too - it is most frustrating, and makes it impossible to give my code to others to use. Using xlwings to update an excel sheet that already contains filters, I get a pop-up error message - naming conflict with _FilterDatabase. I have deleted this Name manually and using VBA macros, as most threads lead towards, but the error keeps coming back intermitantly. A solution would be great?

Comment: As evident from the lack of answers and time elapsed since my question was posted, there seems to be no answer for it. I have not found any so far and just kinda given up :/

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't see where you apply the filter but before you apply the filter have you tried turning the AutoFilterMode to False then add the filter? For example

```
    sh_data.Rows(1).AutoFilter(Field=1, Criteria1='B')
```

Comment: I didnt apply the filter with the script. The target excel file should be a "data dump" so to speak, with data being continuously imported through the script. The issue is not really with python and maybe not even with win32com, but Excel itself.
If the Excel sheet (at any point in time) had a filter (even if it was since removed), no matter if created through the script or manually added, I will get this error when the script is trying to access the Workbook

Comment: I also done similar thing in my code and didn't seem to encounter any issue at all so don't think it is an Excel problem either? I normally use a combination xlwings to dump data and win32com to clear data, set style/formatting etc... (One thing to note is my workbook objects are created inside the main function and passed as paramters to all sub-functions)

Comment: For example:
``` 
def processing_data():
    wb_win = Excel.Workbooks.Add()
    wb_xw = xw.books[wb_win.Name]

    load_data(wb_win=wb_win, wb_xw=wb_xw)
    

def load_data(wb_win, wb_xw)
    ws_win = wb_win.Sheets(ws_name)
    ws_win.AutoFilterMode = False
    ws_win.ClearContents()
    wb_xw.sheets[ws_name].range('A2').value = data['datapoint']
    return True

Comment: I pass the Worksheet instead, I don't think the placement of the code should have an impact here. But if you cannot reproduce the issue, that is interesting. I tried it on different files and with different colleagues PCs and I get the same issue everywhere.

Comment: then it is something in the code that Excel didn't like then. Are you adding any range names or doing any other changes to the spreadsheet besides pasting data?

Comment: Yes. All of my interactions from the script are shown above (minus a few more data assignments) all I do is open the Workbook, insert new Ranges on A2:H2 and fill the data into each range.

Answer (score 0):

I've had difficulty using xlwings to export data into Excel files with filters for years. I'd hoped that xlwings would address this limitation.

Meanwhile, I've recently tried two possible solutions. Both need to be repeated whenever new filter(s) are added to the sheet. I'm not sure if either solution works in the long term or for all situations.

**Solution 1** from ExtendOffice

Unhide hidden name values, and then change the _FilterDatabase name via NameManager after running the following macro:

```
   Sub ShowNames()
     'Update 20140318
      Dim xName As Name
      For Each xName In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Names
         xName.Visible = True
      Next
   End Sub
```

**Solution 2** adapted from Professor Excel.

1. Make a backup copy of your Excel workbook (important!!!!).
2. From file name, delete .xlsx and replace it with .zip.
3. Open .zip file and navigate to “xl” folder, and move “workbook.xml” into a working directory.
4. Open “workbook.xml” (right-click “Open with” –> “Notepad”) and change
   the defined name "_FilterDatabase" between  and  to "_FilterDatabase2".
5. Save workbook.xml and return it to xl folder
6. Rename the .zip-file back to .xlsx.
7. Open .xlsx file and allow excel to recover the file.
8. Cross fingers and hope it works.