# Apply Autofilter to worksheet using Python

Tags: python, excel, win32com, xlsxwriter

I tried to apply autofilter to an existing worksheet using but the process keeps on failing on the autofilter line. I did quite a bit of research online and couldn't find why my isn't working or whether there is any alternative ways. Can anyone please help? (P.S. I also tried using win32com [example: ws_win32.AutoFilter()] and that also didn't work)

My sample code:

```
def _set_autofilter(self):
    wb_xlsw = xlsxwriter.Workbook('ExistingWorkbook.xlsb')
    ws_xlsw = wb_xlsw.get_worksheet_by_name('Data')
    ws_xlsw.autofilter('A1:D19904')
```

Comment: Since xlsxwriter is not an Option, you can just try it with win32com. You just have to simulate the VBA code in Python: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofilter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just stay within win32com to achieve this:

```
data = [{"test1": 1, "test2": 1}, {"test1": 2, "test2": 2}, {"test1": 3, "test2": 3}, {"test1": 4, "test2": 4}]

import win32com.client as win32
def openExcel():

    xl = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
    wb = xl.Workbooks.Add()
    ws = wb.Sheets(1)
    xl.Visible = True

    return ws

def print2Excel(datapoint:dict, ws):
    print(datapoint)

    const = win32.constants #.Insert()-Methods keywargs are packaged into const.
    ws.Range("A2:B2").Insert(const.xlShiftDown, const.xlFormatFromRightOrBelow)
    ws.Cells(2,1).Value = datapoint["test1"]
    ws.Cells(2,2).Value = datapoint["test2"]

def setAutoFilter(ws):
    ws.Range("A:A").AutoFilter(Field=1, Criteria1=3)

def main():
    ws = openExcel()
    ws.Cells(1,1).Value = "test1"
    ws.Cells(1,2).Value = "test2"
    for datapoint in data:
        print2Excel(datapoint, ws)
    setAutoFilter(ws)

main()
```

I cannot seem to be able to get the Criteria of the AutoFilter to use an Array, though.
ws.Range("A:A").AutoFilter(Field=1, Criteria1=[1, 3]) will run, but only filters for the last item in the list (3).
Whereas the VBA-Syntax ws.Range("A:A").AutoFilter(Field=1, Criteria1=Array(1, 3)) will trigger an exception.

Comment: Also, if you want to access a file that has Filters on it, win32com will make a fuss. If you know of or find out a workaround for this, please post it on my question on the topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58303237/naming-conflict-filterdatabase-when-feeding-excel-with-data-from-win32com

Comment: Thank you. I solved the issue now. Was missing the Field parameter which apparently is a compulsory field for Filter to work. The code that failed: ```ws_win.Rows(1).AutoFilter()```  The code that working now: ```ws_win.Rows(1).AutoFilter(Field=1)```  This way I don't even have to know how many rows of data existed and the script will apply the filter to all. Thank you once again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to `get_worksheet_by_name()` a worksheet with that name if you haven't created one in XlsxWriter.

If you are trying to read an existing file then you can't do that with XlsxWriter. It only creates new files.